# Math.random() javascript function *undefined* on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

In first place, I am convinced that this is a trivial question, but I cannot understand why this is happening and I couldn't find an answer anywhere else. I googled my issue with little success, but if I missed something and just wasted your time please point me in the right direction and accept my humble excuses.

That said, here is what happens. I am building a simple script to display a graph drawn by a distributed algorithm (giraph) and I am working on Linux. I import all the libraries and, in particular, jQuery and everything works in Firefox (version 36.0.1). Switching to Chrome (version 41.0.2272.89 (64-bit)), the page stops working. Investigating the issue, I found out that the error was inside the `jQuery.extend()` function into the jQuery library, at the following line:

```
expando: "jQuery" + ( version + Math.random() ).replace( /\D/g, "" ),
```

In fact, trying to invoke `Math.random()` into the browser console leads to:

```
> Math.random();
> Uncaught TypeError: Undefined is not a function
```

Anyway, while typing the console autocompletes the "Math" variable, with the following result:

```
> Math
> function (){return "";}
```

This does not happen with Chrome on MacOS X Mavericks. Did anybody experience this kind of behaviour before?

**EDIT:** Unfortunately, I don't think that this is a namespace conflict. In my library I import only one other library (other than jQuery), which is [Sigma js](http://sigmajs.org/). As suggested, I wrote Math in the console and tried to understand which library did override Math (using "Show Function Definition"), with the following result, taken from a file named "VM53" (which I did not write and/or linked directly).

```
(function (){
    for (var i in window)
    {
    try {
            var jsType = typeof window[i];
            switch (jsType.toUpperCase())
            {                   
                case "FUNCTION": 
                    if (window[i] !== window.location)
                    {
                        if (window[i] === window.open || (window.showModelessDialog && window[i] === window.showModelessDialog))
                            window[i] = function(){return true;};
                        else if (window[i] === window.onbeforeunload)   // To try to fix onbeforeunload pop ups some users report seeing but I can't replicate.
                            window.onbeforeunload = null;
                        else if (window[i] === window.onunload)
                            window.onunload = null;                             
                        else
                            window[i] = function(){return "";};
                    }
                    break;                          
            }           
        }
        catch(err)
        {}      
    }

    for (var i in document)
    {
        try {
            var jsType = typeof document[i];
            switch (jsType.toUpperCase())
            {                   
                case "FUNCTION":
                    document[i] = function(){return "";};
                    break;                  
            }           
        }
        catch(err)
        {}      
    }

    try {
        eval = function(){return "";};              
        unescape = function(){return "";};
        String = function(){return "";};
        parseInt = function(){return "";};
        parseFloat = function(){return "";};
        Number = function(){return "";};
        isNaN = function(){return "";};
        isFinite = function(){return "";};
        escape = function(){return "";};
        encodeURIComponent = function(){return "";};
        encodeURI = function(){return "";};
        decodeURIComponent = function(){return "";};
        decodeURI = function(){return "";};
        Array = function(){return "";};
        Boolean = function(){return "";};
        Date = function(){return "";};
        Math = function(){return "";};
        Number = function(){return "";};
        RegExp = function(){return "";};

        var oNav = navigator;
        navigator = function(){return "";};
        oNav = null;            
    }
    catch(err)
    {}

})();
```

Comment: That is indeed interesting :)

Comment: Some script overrided `Math.random`. Try to remove other `<script>` tags from page and see what causes error.

Comment: Or a Chrome extension disables `Math` for some reason. Does it work if you try it in incognito mode?

Comment: Math.random() is native JavaScript code, so the only thing that comes to my mind is that somewhere in your code you have overwritten Math object.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something overrides `Math` in your code.

Execute `Math` in your chrome console. Execute context menu on it and select "Show function definition". This will probably lead you to "Sources" panel and show script where it is being overriden.

**EDIT:** this is chrome extension called `notscripts`. Disable it. Here is the source code for proof: [webarchive](https://web.archive.org/web/20151119085234/https://code.google.com/p/notscripts/source/browse/trunk/blockStart.js?r=8)

Comment: if everything is fine and you found this stuff, find its author on GitHub, build trust with him, get his home address, find something very heavy and show this a*****e that overriding language is the bad idea indeed =)

Comment: As I said, I knew it was something trivial *grabs cone of shame*.

Comment: Glen, the link is now broken. I would suggest pointing it here now: https://code.google.com/archive/p/notscripts/

Comment: @AlexisWilke Thanks for pointing it out. I replace link with webarchive cached copy.

Answer (score 2):

Another library on your page is overriding the `Math` object. This is one of the reasons that *polluting* the Global Namespace is frowned upon.

For reference `Math` should return the following

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found another situation that could cause this to happen. I was converting a PHP function to a JS function and I had the following line:

```
ticks += "," . Math.floor(yyy * intMax);
```

Changing it to

```
ticks += "," + Math.floor(yyy * intMax);
```

solved the problem

Comment: That really had nothing to do with the problem. `Math.random()` is clearly a JavaScript function and it should continue to work for pretty much ever.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, **NotScript** got automatically installed in my Chrome browser on Ubuntu 16.04. That inserts the script you show in your update just after the `<html>` tag.

I had to go to the settings, look at the extensions, disable the **NotScripts** and then restart Chrome to it would be gone.

[image: Chromium Extensions showing NotScripts 0.9.6 enabled]

On Ubuntu, this must be very recent or the script got updated recently because I ran the exact same test in Chrome, with the exact same scripts, a few days ago, and it was working just fine.

Interestingly enough, it looks like it was [removed 2 years ago](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/chrome/report-a-problem-and-get-troubleshooting-help/windows7/Stable/J7Kx4QK04L4) (Nov 2014) and maybe re-added recently?