# javascript TypeError: Math.random is not a function on chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, math, random

I use a Math.random() function in a AngularJS Code

```
$scope.runFull = function () {
var rand;
    do {
        rand = Math.random();
        ...
    } while ($scope.cond < 5400); // 90 minutes         
};
$scope.runFull();
```

My Chrome console return **javascript TypeError: Math.random is not a function**

I put Math in watcher and I find Math.abs, Math.acos, Math...., Math.random, Math....

Comment: http://jsbin.com/kiteca/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: Can you create an example where we can reproduce the error?

Comment: This link may help you.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29072744/math-random-javascript-function-undefined-on-chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29072744/math-random-javascript-function-undefined-on-chrome)

Comment: sushmit.patil, I 've read this article, but I still have the problem. no solution is given

Comment: Make sure you don't define a  `Math` variable. `var Math = {}; Math.random() => Uncaught TypeError: Math.random is not a function` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing

Comment: Math.random() is surely not causing this error, can you create a plunk so that we can scan the whole code?

Comment: I create a plunk example, but it is OK: http://plnkr.co/edit/2rOwSBBJkhY3SumcgqPw?p=preview

Comment: so it's probably you are overriding the `Math` object. try to do in your console `Math`, and what's the result?

Comment: YES, thank you very much everyone, I have a angularjs service named "Math".

Comment: You should have provided the exact code in the plunk that you were running. Anyways, your welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My error was :** angular.module('xxxxxApp')
    .controller('FullController', function ($scope, $interval, xxxxService, yyyyService, ..., **Math**, Principal) {

YES, thank you very much everyone, I have a angularjs service named "Math".

Solution: **I rename my "Math" service in "Mathematic"** and I can use Math.random() :)

Answer (score 2):

either Math or Math.random is overridden. run Math.random() as you first line of code and see what happens.

Comment: if I overridden the line : rand = Math.random(); My code is OK

Comment: run that line in the start of your project. you might be loading a package which has a bug.

Comment: I use AngulasJS with some services, I can switch the order. When we use AngulasJS, never create a service name "Math".